# Function works everywhere, how to keep it to execute when creating a new post

Tags: php, posts, functions

I have a function that downloads a portion of a MP3 file to analyze the file size and the duration. My problem I have with my function is that it works everywhere. When I try to delete a post on the edit.php panel, it gives me a timeout but it does delete the post when I go back to edit.php. Is there a way to have a function execute code when a post is being created and not being updated or on edit.php?

```
function analyze_mp3( $post_id, $post ){
if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
    $filename = tempnam('/tmp','getid3');
    if (file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'podcast_url', true ), false, null, 0, 152608654))) {
        if (require_once( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ). 'id3/getid3.php' )) {
            $getID3 = new getID3;
            $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
        }
        unlink($filename);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'length', $ThisFileInfo[filesize] ); 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'time', $ThisFileInfo[playtime_string] );
    }
}};
add_action( 'save_post', 'analyze_mp3', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_post` accepts one more parameter `$update`.

```
$update : Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
```

So in your code

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'analyze_mp3', 10, 3 );

function analyze_mp3( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    if($update)
        return;
    //your code
}
```

Please check syntax/documentation. Have not tried or tested this.

Comment: Above didn't work